# How do I correctly use compareWith with Reactive Forms in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

Is this the correct way to do it? Official docs only gave us an example on how to use it with Template-driven Forms and not Reactive Forms.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Toppings" formControlName="toppings" [compareWith]="compareFn" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of (toppings$ | async)" [value]="topping.id">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

pizzaForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: ['1'],
    name: ['Foo'],
    topping: [
        [
            { id: 1, name: 'Foo'}
         , 
            { id: 2, name: 'Bar' }
        ]
    ],
})

compareFn(a: any, b: any): boolean {
    return a.id === b.id;
}
```

Comment: what you exactly wants to compare?

Comment: It is available for Reactive Forms and Template Forms both.